# In which order are the "onfocusin" and "onfocusout" events triggered?

Tags: dom-events, onfocus

Lets say I have two elements: `elm_1` and `elm_2` and a variable `var x = 1`

The elements have the following events:

`elm_1.addEventListener('focusout', () => x = 1)`

`elm_2.addEventListener('focusin', () => x = 2)`

My question is if I change focus from `elm_1` to `elm_2`, can I be sure which event triggers first? Will `x` be equal to 1 or 2 after I have changed focus? And I don't mean just in this particular case, I am asking how/if I can be 100% sure of which event is executed first so that regardless of what is inside the functions, I can know what will happen first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can be sure that `focusout` always fire on the losing focus element before `focusin` is raised on the new element. So in your particular case the variable `x` would be 2 after both events fired.

Source:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent#order_of_events

Note that even though some implementations shifted the order of some events, both `focusout` and `focusin` are fixed in that order.